# compare date with current time in jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl, date-comparison

Hello I'm trying compare a date with current time using jstl in a jsp file.
How can I compare a date with the current time using jstl?
I have this:

```
<jsp:useBean id="currentDate" type="java.util.Date"/>  
<fmt:formatDate var="now" value="${currentDate} pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/>  

<c:if test="${ h.time < now }">
  <h1>print something</h1>
</c:if>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: What's happening differently to what you'd expected & what have you tried so far to fix it? You haven't really asked a question here…

Comment: Have you read any of the documentation on the Date class?

Comment: @Athif: your bounty is confusing. The current question is already answered (although it's poorly explained). How exactly is the currently accepted answer unhelpful to you? What problems exactly are you still facing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

convert the time to a date and compare it with the current date.

**Conversion to date:**

```
<jsp:useBean id="dateValue" class="java.util.Date" />
<jsp:setProperty name="dateValue" property="time" value="${h.time}" />
```

Comparision:

```
<c:if test="${dateValue le now}">
    //do something
</c:if>
```

Comment: thanks, but I get this: `Cannot convert 07-01-14 12:00 AM of type class java.sql.Timestamp to long`

Comment: what is h.time ? is it a long or a date object?

Comment: a var from controller, is a Date object.

Comment: I think the issue is one of them is a java.util.Date and the other is a java.sql.date. Either convert them both to the same Date object or convert them both to a time(long format) and do the comparison.

Answer (score 6):

I am sharing some ways to solve the issue.

### First:

I am going to presume it is a `java.util.Date`.

You can get the current date like this

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date"/>
```

You can then compare them using an EL expression:

```
{code}
<c:if test="${submitDate < now}">
We have not yet reached the submit date.
</c:if>{code}
```

EL uses the java compareTo methods, so both of your objects must be of the same class in order for this comparision to work.

If you get back a String from the database, you would have to use  to get a java date.
If you get back a `java.sql.Date` from the database, it would get trickier. The hack would be to go `java.sql.Date -> String -> java.util.Date using <fmt:formatDate> and <fmt:parseDate>`

### Resource link:

[compare current date with dat from db by JSTL](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1398782?start=0&tstart=0)

---

### Second:

```
<fmt:parseDate value="${found.submitDate}" pattern="yy/MM/dd" var="submitDate"/>
                                 <c:if test="${submitDate <now}">
                                     We have not yet reached the submit date.
                                 </c:if>
```

---

### Third:

One clean way is to use the `jsp:useBean` tag to create a page-scoped variable containing the current date/time and then use normal JSTL to compare the objects.

First create the page-scoped `java.util.Date object` (using jsp:useBean), then use ${now} to reference the current date/time. This is a regular JSP object now and so the normal JSTL operators work with this variable:

```
<jsp:useBean id="now" class="java.util.Date"/>

<c:if test="${someEvent.startDate lt now}">
   It's history!
</c:if>
```

### Resource Link:

[JSTL date comparisons with the current time (now) in JSPs](http://blog.andrewbeacock.com/2009/05/jstl-date-comparisons-with-current-time.html)

Comment: What about comparing with hours, as in a few hours ago or yesterday.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bad practice to have logic inside of you view layer.

What you should instead do, is make the calculations inside of the controller and put the result in the view, as a variable, and use inside of the condition:

```
<c:if test="${timeLessThanNow}">
  <h1>print something</h1>
</c:if>
```